# loading multiple JSON files in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, json

I have two different JSON files and they have the same attributes in them. I'm able to load them by using two promises in my service but when I go in my HTML and try to display my data they display the same thing.

This is my service:

```
$http.get("data.json");

            //User JSON api
            $http.get("data1.json")
                .then(function (response) {
                        dataRecievedCallback(response.data);
                    }
```

Should I assign my $http.get to a variable, if yes How can I do that and do I need to change anything in my controller?
I haven't been coding for long and I'm new to angular so all the help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
$http.get("data.json")
      .then(function (response) {
           $scope.foo = response.data;
       }
$http.get("data1.json")
      .then(function (response) {
           $scope.bar = response.data;
       }
```

Not sure about your "dataRecievedCallback()" function, if your function set the data into the same variable, the second $http call will overwrite the first one.

Comment: Should I just delete my "dataRecievedCallback()"?

Comment: One more question, I dont want to elaborate my data, I want to display it as it is. Do I need to make any changes to my controller? Because I keep getting an error message "Cannot set property 'firstData' of undefined" where firstData is $scope.foo in your example.

Comment: In this case you may remove your `dataReceivedCallback()`, for `Cannot set property 'firstData' of undefined` most likely you are setting your `$scope.firstData` before your `$http` return which causing your `$scope.firstData` to be undefined.